# Why is $E[(X − b) ^2 ]$ minimal when $b = µ$?

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

If $X$ is a random variable with a mean µ and a variance $σ^2$, why is $$E[(X − b) ^2 ]$$ minimal when $b = µ$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ \mathbb E[(X-b)^2] = \mathbb E[X^2 - 2 b X + b^2] = 
\mathbb E[X^2] - 2 b \mathbb E[X] + b^2 = \sigma^2 + (b-\mu)^2$$